# Angular directive communications

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my **JS code**

```
a.directive("easyuiLinkbutton", function () {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {},
    controller: function () {
        this.initialize = function (elem, attrs) {
            $(elem).linkbutton({
                iconCls: attrs.iconCls
            });
        }
    }
  };
});

a.directive("newCase", function (caseMVCService) {
return {
    require: '^easyuiLinkbutton',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, easyuiLinkbuttonCrtl) {
        easyuiLinkbuttonCrtl.initialize(elem, attrs);
    }
  };
});
```

and **HTML**

```
 <easyui-linkbutton>
        <new-case iconCls="icon-add" plain="false"></a>
    </easyui-linkbutton>
```

It works fine.

Now I am trying to do something like this:

```
<easyui-linkbutton></easyui-linkbutton>
<new-case iconCls="icon-add" plain="false"></a>
```

It does not work that way complaining about this line:

```
require: '^easyuiLinkbutton',
```

Is it possible to get what I am trying to do working?

Thanks

Comment: `require: '^easyuiLinkbutton',` searches directive `easyuiLinkbutton` upstream. In your trial, they are in parallel.

Comment: I tried require: 'easyuiLinkbutton' too, did not work.

Comment: `require: 'easyuiLinkbutton'` searches on the same element. Not found option to search siblings. Maybe you need a factory/service

Comment: Ok, I see. A bit better. so this works:         <easyui-linkbutton new-case iconCls="icon-add" plain="false"></easyui-linkbutton>
But, is it possible to get working what I want: <easyui-linkbutton></easyui-linkbutton>
<new-case iconCls="icon-add" plain="false"></new-case> How would I use factory/service for that?

Comment: AFAIK, you would need to embed them both in a parent directive to do that, and communicate via this common ancestor directive controller.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, but what I am thinking to do is to have a single place somewhere in the begging of the application where I would initialize all my base directives thus they will be available on every screen I open.

Comment: Then using `parent/child` structure is not what you want?